# How to redirect someone automatically within given time using only HTML/CSS excluding JS or <meta>

Tags: html, css, redirect, time

I was looking at how i can redirect a viewer on a website to another part of the website with in given time but all i found is that i can do it only with JavaScript or using this  code, `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; url='https://www.google.com'" />` so is there a way to do this using only HTML/CSS

Comment: Perhaps someone can provide a solution, but I don't believe that this is possible.

Comment: `<meta>` tags _are_ HTML. It's not possible with CSS or other HTML tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do that using only Html or Css since you need a script that can treat time.

If the reason why you don't want to use JS is due to the "difficulty", trust me it's very simple, many tutorials are available on YouTube for example.

Comment: Meta tag redirects are HTML, and can be set to take effect after a specific duration.

Comment: CSS can handle the time aspect; there are ways of not starting an animation after 3 seconds, for instance. There's just no way to redirect using CSS.

Comment: It's not because of difficulty it was just a school challange to use HTML/CSS to create a website. Thanks everyone!